# Kibana: Search pattern for stracktrace does not retrieve results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I try to filter types of NullPointer Exceptions in Kibana. I find results for stacktrace:"java.lang.NullPointerException:\ null\ at", but none for  stacktrace:"java.lang.NullPointerException:\ null\ at\ com". Although there are enough stack traces of the form in Kibana. e.g.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mycompany.service.SomeService.getValue(myFile.java:130)
```

Does anybody know why that could be?

Comment: I assume your field is not tokenized correctly and "com.mycompany.service.SomeService.getValue" is considered a single token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if analyzer and tokenizer of your stack trace field work as expected:

```
GET indexname/_analyze
{
  "field": "stacktrace",
  "text": "java.lang.NullPointerException: null\nat com.mycompany.service.SomeService.getValue(myFile.java:130)"
}

GET indexname/_analyze
{
  "field": "stacktrace",
  "text": "java.lang.NullPointerException:\ null\ at\ com"
}
```

Find a detailed explanation of the [Anaylize API in the Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

You might also be interested in the [field mappings of your index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) or the [mapping of a single field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-field-mapping.html):

```
GET indexname/_mapping
GET indexname/_mapping/field/stacktrace
```

Generals details about [Text analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) is available in the docs too, which explain the concepts and how to use and configure tokenizers, analyzers, filters, and normalizers.